# django update multiple records

Tags: django

I'm trying to change the group of my contacts all at once based on a list of id's that have been sent in a  form POST.

```
@login_required
def contact_move(request, group_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        group = Group.objects.get(pk=group_id)
        Contact.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST["contacts"]).update(group=group)
```

contacts post looks like this.
5049, 5041

However, nothing updates and I get no errors. What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`request.POST.getlist("contacts")`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

> Returns the data with the requested key, as a Python list. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and no default value was provided. It’s guaranteed to return a list of some sort unless the default value was no list.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there `getlist` is needed try:

```
getIDs = request.POST.getlist("contacts")
        Contact.objects.filter(id__in=getIDs).update(group=group)
```